# Unable to clone project from Team Foundation Server

Tags: git, tfs, version-control

I'm working in project which uses Team Foundation Server. We are provided with credentials for server but now I am unable to clone that repo from there, I tried plugin for TFS in Android Studio but no success, also while creating new repository it is giving error:

> your account does not have edit project level information

I am using Team Foundation Server for first time can anyone help me on cloning repository from Team foundation server and how to create new repo there? Any help will be more helpful.

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git?

Comment: @Daniel Mann TFVC

Comment: @HardikMehta You mention "clone" and "creating a new repository".  Those are git concepts, not TFVC.  (For example, you only have _one_ TFVC repository for the entire Project Collection, you cannot create a second with any level of permission.)  Are you sure you're not using Git?  What error message are you getting when you try to clone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contract to your TFS administrator to set the "Edit Project-level information" to Allow for your account in the Team Project Security page. 
[image]

Update:

In TFVC, it's not called "Clone repository", it's "map a workspace".  Refer to this [document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/create-work-workspaces), it tells about how to create a workspace in your local machine for a team project.

Comment: now I have this permission can you please tell how can I clone this repo in order to commit my code.i am using the android studio.

Comment: @HardikMehta I have updated by reply to give you a link about how to map a workspace.

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable help.also according to document I have to add files to repository (like git commit) in order to commit code.